# USB 3.0 video card supporting dual-link DVI 2560x1440?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I have an available USB 3 port on my laptop, and I'd like to run a 2560x1440 monitor whose ONLY input is a dual-link DVI port. All the USB 3 adapters I've seen have HDMI or DisplayPort, or just single-link DVI. Does anyone know of a device that would work?

Comment: Have you looked into a DP to Dual Link DVI dongle?

Comment: Or an HDMI to dual-link DVI dongle. Very cheap at Monoprice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

[HP Dual Output USB Graphics Adapter (C5U89AT)](http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product/sku/10468695)

Requires only a usb 3 port and outputs to dvi dual link at 2560 * 1600 or using both the dvi and the display port at a lower res.

Comment: In the linked specifications you can see that the DVI is capable of up to 1920 x 1200 or 2048 x 1152. The full resolution is only over DisplayPort. --- Can you please show where is it specified that you can get DVI dual link at 2560 x 1600?

Comment: That link does say it supports 2560 x 1600. But this was a long time ago, and I'd since found another adapter (a DisplayLink one) that does the same thing. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you’re out of luck.  I also have a notebook with a USB 3.0 port and a 30-inch 2560x1600 DVI-only monitor.  I’ve spent several months researching options.  There’s no product converting USB 3.0 to DVI directly, I have not found even any planned for the future.

So, I ended up buying a USB 3.0 to DisplayPort Adapter (by LINDY) and a Dell BizLink DisplayPort to DVI-D Dual Link Adapter.  Both of them support 2560x1600 separately. That’s the option suggested by lexvegas.

But the problem is that they just don’t work together.  It seems that there’s an incompatibly issue between their chipsets, so the whole construct is still limited to this weird but prominent resolution of 2048x1152.

I spent over $200 on both (with no way to return them), so this money is just wasted!
There are several USB-DP and DP-DVI products on the market, but they are all based on the same chipsets, so actual brands don’t matter here.

So, unfortunately we’re out of luck here, I ended up buying another 30-inch monitor with Displayport.

But at least I just saved you (and many others with a similar problem) $200.

Comment: Lindy's [Website](http://www.lindy-usa.com/usb-30-to-displayport-adapter-43171.html) states why your adapters are "incompatible": _Note: Does not support Dual Mode DP / DP++ / Adapters to DVI/HDMI/VGA_. However, Dual Link DVI is required to drive a display of that resolution.

Comment: Double active conversion rarely works as the monitor detect gets botched and it defaults to something unsatisfactory. The weird 2048x1152 is it defaulting to single link DVI for some reason.